# concat two query result with union in two different column

Tags: sql

Hi i want concat two sql query result:

```
select nome 
from prodotto as nome 
  inner join prodotto_presente  
         on codice_prodotto=codice 
        and quantità_prodotto<soglia_minima 
        and codice_reparto=125 
        and cod_supermercato=2345
union 
select stima_tempo_consegna 
from fornitore as strima 
  inner join supermercato_ordine 
          on codicefornit=codice 
         and codice_supermercato=2345 
   inner join prodotto_presente 
          on odotto_presente.codice_prodotto = supermercato_ordine.codice_prodotto 
         and quantità_prodotto<soglia_minima 
   inner join prodotto 
           on prodotto_presente.codice_prodotto=prodotto.codice 
          and codice_reparto=125;
```

The output in one table that is the union of two query but I want two table output.
I want this output:

```
Nome    strima
---------------
ssss    yyyyy
uuuu    oooo
```

How i do it?

Comment: For me it seems, you need not UNION, but JOIN.It would be nice if you could share some sample data and desired result

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your sample seems you need  the join between the two queries

```
    select t1.nome, t2.strima
    from  (
    select codice, nome 
    from prodotto
    inner join prodotto_presente  on codice_prodotto=codice and quantità_prodotto<soglia_minima 
        and codice_reparto=125 
            and cod_supermercato=2345 ) t1
    INNER JOIN (
    select codicestima_tempo_consegna strima
    from fornitore 
    inner join supermercato_ordine on codicefornit=codice 
        and codice_supermercato=2345 
    inner join prodotto_presente on prodotto_presente.codice_prodotto=supermercato_ordine.codice_prodotto 
        and quantità_prodotto<soglia_minima 
    inner join prodotto on prodotto_presente.codice_prodotto=prodotto.codice 
        and codice_reparto=125
    ) t2 on t1.codice = t2.codice
```